# Was the Buddha known to chant during his meditation?

Tags: the-buddha, mantra, meditation-concentration, chant

Did the Buddha chant some mantra or holy word throughout his meditation? Or he was just silent to realize what is coming through him to interpret?

Comment: There is a sutra in the pali-canon where he explicitely said that he disliked a) translation of his dicourses into the (upper-class/theological/intellectual) language of Sanscrit, and b) chanting his discourses. I don't have the sutra-index at hand; if I find it (and you want it) I'll post it as an answer (but perhaps you find it your self at accesstoinsight.com (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more like contemplating rather chanting.

origination or dependent arising, Pratītyasamutpāda. He told Ananda he would contemplate, recite Pratītyasamutpāda when he was alone.

Answer (score 1):

During his developmental years (before he became Enlightened) he might have.
This is because mantras are a way for you to match vibration with a particular deity and thus receive their assistance.

The Buddha gave many such great mantras including the Zhunti mantra but a Buddha has no reason to use them because the Buddhas are all connected simultaneously through their uncovered dharmakaya/Tathagatagarba/Buddha-nature.